# How to make a jOOQ Configuration object?

Tags: java, jooq

I want to have my jOOQ connection stored so I can access it from all my classes without having to specify the url, username, password, etc.

I found [this page](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/) from the jOOQ documentation. I understand I need to use DSLContext, but right now I create a new context in every class.
My eye fell on this piece of info from that same page:

> If you do not have a **reference to a pre-existing Configuration object** (e.g. created from org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration), the various overloaded DSL.using() methods will create one for you.

So as far as I understand, this is what I need to have. This may sound like a noob question, but: how do I make a "pre-existing Configuration object" and how do I create a "reference" to that?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create a new [`DefaultConfiguration`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultConfiguration.html), e.g.

```
Configuration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration()
    .set(dataSource)
    .set(dialect)
    .set(settings)
    .set(...);
```

People often create such a `DefaultConfiguration` using Spring and then inject that into all the relevant classes, see e.g. this page from the manual:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-with-spring